# Get surrounding pixels in array

Tags: c#, arrays, math, pixel

Hey. My maths isn't great so I'm hoping someone can help me with this. I have a 1D array of pixels (representing a 2d image). In order to access a specific pixel, I'm using this formula:

```
image.Pixels[row * imageWidth + col] = pixelColor;
```

This is working, but I would also like to include pixels around the selected pixel. What's the fastest way, without using pointers directly, to get a group of pixels around the selected pixel with a radius of r and set their values to pixelColor? I'm trying to create a paint-type app and would like to vary brush sizes, which would be dictated by the radius size.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: The easiest way would be to use a 2D array. Or at the very least, to set up a property so you can access it like a 2D array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know C# specifically, but something to the effect of this should do you

```
for (i=-r ; i< r ; i++) {
    for (j=-(r - i); j<(r - i); j++) {
       image.Pixels[(row+i)*imageWidth + (col+j)]=pixelColour;
    }
}
```

---

Edit the above actually paints a diamond, i've given my first hack idea to do a proper circle below

```
for (i=-r ; i<r ; i++) {
    for (j=-r; j<r; j++) {
       if((i*i + j*j)<(r*r)){
           image.Pixels[(row+i)*imageWidth + (col+j)]=pixelColour;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're actually painting a diamond, not a circle. That can be easily fixed, though.

Answer (score 3):

The simple slow way would be to step through the range of pixels in row +- r and col +- r, and calculate the distance from row and col is not greater than r. Distance from col,row is squareroot (difference in x squared + difference in y squared).

A slightly faster way is to compare the square of the radius to the difference in x squared + difference in y squared as they are comparable.

Still faster is [Bresenham's circle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm),

Another article:
[Bresenham's Line and Circle Algorithms](http://www.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article767.asp)

Once you have the distance from col for any row, you can fill the pixels from col - distance to col + distance, no need to calculate both. So you can get away with calculating only half the circle.